# Start Play Application and Close Window

Tags: batch-file, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a play application on a Windows 7 machine which I want to start via double click on a batch file.

This batch file starts a service. Calls the play application to run in production mode, waits for 5 seconds and open a browser with a specified url.

Therefore I used the following script:

```
call net start service1
CALL "D:\play-1.2.5\play.bat" start --%%%%prod -Dprecompiled=true
TIMEOUT /T 4
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" localhost:9000
exit
```

Now when I start the batch file the window opens and all commands are executed. Sadly Play is still writing his output to cmd and the window is not disappearing. If I close the window manually play is stop executing.

If I run play with "play start" from cmd, play is starting in the background and everything is fine. Play still runs even if I close the window.

I want to have exactly this behaviour when I start the application with my batch file.

Thanks

Comment: In my Windows age I have struggled with this as well. But I ended up creating a scheduled tasks as my requirements changed.. In Mac I `start play` and then `CTRL`+`C` to close terminal..

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a linux-like environment, I' d recommend you to use 'nohup' command and a '&' sign in the end. However, as far as I know there is no direct equivalent of beautiful 'nohup' command on Windows, unfortunately. So, what I can think of is, you can create a tiny win api application that utilizes [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command and give it the required parameter to hide command line window as soon as the process is created. There are also other process creation functions such as [WinExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you can use to hide command line.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention that I am using Windows 7 as OS. I updated my question.

Comment: @Gambo, you didn't need to mention that, code you posted in your question is definitelly in Windows style.

Comment: [Here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?302501-Processes-How-can-I-start-a-process) you can find a snippet, showing how to create a new process in Windows environment(below the screen). Just create a new small C project, paste this code, parametrize the command line string, and run this new project' s executable with the command that runs your play project normally

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Play is so I can only take a guess :) but try using the batch without the `call`'s as I don't think they are necessary, and you never know, might fix the issue.

Comment: I tried but the batch is stopping and waiting for the process with blinking cursor

Answer (score 0):

1) You see Play's output because ot redirect only system.out but write system.err to the same console.

2) I also have this problem and looking for a solution. As a workaround you could try to use some Java Wrapper and install your Play! application as a Windows Service.

3) Play! app could be started via Ant task. I haven't tried this yet.